# Set Alias Names to Values in a Field of a Database Table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

If I have a MySQL table looking something like this:

```
| NAME | STATUS | DESIGNATION |
-------------------------------
| ABCD |      0 |          MD |
| DCFG |      1 |         CEO |
| AHSG |      1 |          DD |
```

Is it possible to run a MySQL query to get output like this:

```
| NAME | STATUS |             DESIGNATION |
-------------------------------------------
| ABCD |     No |       Managing Director |
| DCFG |    YES | Chief Executive Officer |
| AHSG |    YES |         Deputy Director |
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `CASE` statement for that:

```
SELECT Name
      ,CASE Status 
       WHEN 0 THEN 'No' 
       WHEN 1 THEN 'YES' 
       END AS Status 
      ,CASE Designation 
       WHEN 'MD' THEN 'Managing Director' 
       WHEN 'CEO' THEN 'Chief Executive Officer' 
       WHEN 'DD' THEN 'Deputy Director' 
       END AS Designation  
FROM MyTable;
```

If you have only two conditions then simply use `ELSE` instead of second condition:

```
SELECT Name
      ,CASE Status 
       WHEN 0 THEN 'No' 
       ELSE 'YES'    <--- I mean use this instead of WHEN 1 THEN 'YES'
       END AS Status 
      ,CASE Designation 
       WHEN 'MD' THEN 'Managing Director' 
       WHEN 'CEO' THEN 'Chief Executive Officer' 
       WHEN 'DD' THEN 'Deputy Director' 
       END AS Designation 
FROM MyTable;
```

Result:

```
| NAME | STATUS |             DESIGNATION |
-------------------------------------------
| ABCD |     No |       Managing Director |
| DCFG |    YES | Chief Executive Officer |
| AHSG |    YES |         Deputy Director |
```

#### [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f6736a/1)

Comment: Sorry i've edited my question.. Can you make the answer according to the question ????

Answer (score 4):

Try this query

```
SELECT Emplyee, if (status = 0, 'No', 'Yes') AS 'Status' from table
```

EDITED

```
SELECT 
   Emplyee, 
   if (status = 0, 'No', 'Yes') AS 'Status',
   CASE Designation 
      WHEN 'MD' THEN 'Managing Director' 
     WHEN 'CEO' THEN 'Chief Executive Officer' 
     WHEN 'DD' THEN 'Deputy Director' 
   END AS Designation 
FROM
   table
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: Sorry i've edited my question.. Can you make the answer according to the question ????